# How to refresh data in TeXLive 2013?

Tags: texlive

On TeXLive I managed to add my local directory `texmf`, but now I whant to make changes in it, like adding `TrueType` directory, where I store `*.ttf` files, so XeLaTeX can use them without writing the path. How can it be done?

Comment: What is the OS? On GNU/Linux, you often would simply put the fonts in `~/.fonts` because XeTeX and LuaTeX should be able to access 'system' fonts....

Comment: Linux mint. I'm not making them as system fonts, they are locally stored in the directory.

Comment: Well, I suppose: `mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/truetype` and put them there.  Your so-called `TEXMFHOME` should follow the standard TeX Directory Structure (i.e., TDS).